# Disappear columns when datagrid.datacontext changed

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have some problems with viewing DataGrid (DataGrid is one), when I change it dataContext.

I extract information from sqlite DB and put it into DataTable then I clear DataGrid columns and place new DataTable data into DataGrid, code is here:

```
sqliteDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, sqliteConnection);

if (tableFromDB == null)
tableFromDB = new DataTable();

tableFromDB.Reset();

sqliteDataAdapter.Fill(tableFromDB);

dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
dataGrid.DataContext = tableFromDB;
```

And it's work for one time, when I choose other information from DB and repeat this code I have data (I see it in DataTable ), but number of column = 0 (in DataGrid).

Comment: Why you are removing columns. What happen when you comment following line: dataGrid.Columns.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

When I comment line: dataGrid.Columns.Clear(); I have an exception... But I soleved my problem. After dataGrid.Columns.Clear(); I did it:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in tableFromDB.Columns)
{
   dataGrid.Columns.Add(
     new DataGridTextColumn
     {
        Header = col.ColumnName,
        Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", col.ColumnName))
     });
}

dataGrid.ItemsSource = tableFromDB.Rows;
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```